# How to display an AlertDialog before activity onDestroy, and before the application is closed by user?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-lifecycle

My active Activity runs a bound/unbound service, which is an essential part of the application. I want to display an AlertDialog when the user attempts to close the app when the said Activity and the service is running. I understand that this is not in lines with good UX design, but the functionality is essential and non-resumable, so a user confirmation is required at this step.

I'm already overriding the following method.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //Handle AlertDialog here.
    //Activity must not stop + Application must not close without user confirmation.
}
```

I need to display the AlertDialog in two other conditions besides Back button:

1. The app is in the background (with the foreground service running), and a user tries to kill the apps, e.g. clears all apps from carousel, or clears this app, etc.
2. The app is in the foreground and the user closes the app using Recents button.

**PS**: Are there different methods to support gestures instead of B-H-R buttons?

Comment: while pressing back button its possible, but others are not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it is the android functionality which you can not override. For back button only you can implement the `dialog box`, not for other two keys which are mend to take your app in `taskbar` or go to `home`

Create the method `exitByBackKey()`

```
        AlertDialog alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("Do you want to exit application?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    // do something when the button is clicked
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        System.exit(0);
                        //close();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    // do something when the button is clicked
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        //nothing
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }
```

And now under your `onBackPressed()` call this method.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //Handle AlertDialog here.
    //Activity must not stop + Application must not close without user confirmation.
     exitByBackKey()
}
```

Comment: I'm actually more concerned about properly handling the lifecycle of the service. I have observed that the service remains active even if the app is closed, and the app is not consistently able to resume from the appropriate state. This is what I need to avoid, overall - when this particular activity/service is running, users should not be able to exit without confirmation. Are there any other methods pertaining to Activity and Service that I should look into? @code-dexter

Comment: No, there is no such thing in my knowledge! And neither I have seen an app with this kind of functionality. Please give some example apps so that the developers can relate to and solve your problem!

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Your solution is essentially what I was looking for, but since then I modified the user flow such that I now simply override the onBackPressed() method and display a toast, and no other user input is required.

Comment: In continuation of my comment above, I've noticed that apps like Spotify seem to use a foreground Service to play music. Sometimes, the current song continues to play for 1-3 seconds after I have closed the app (i.e., actual exit, and not minimize). I believe this to be an artefact of the nature of process and thread handling performed by Android itself. This is precisely the behaviour I wished to avoid in case the user closes the app, hence my question.